# C++ ZLib GZipStream Decompression NULL terminated

Tags: c++, zlib, compression, null-terminated

There are a lot of questions out there revolving around zlib and GZipStreams but none that I've found answer this question. I'm using a C# GZipStream to send compressed data to a client. It reads the compressed data in entirely then tries to decompress it. However, each time inflate() is called in the loop it only gets the NULL terminated string. When sending a binary this is a pretty huge problem.

Before I show you code, I just wanted to say that if I write the received compressed bytes to a .gz file and use gzFile/gzopen/gzread/gzclose everything works perfectly. That means all the data is coming in properly. I want to read in the compressed data, decompress it in memory, and have the contents in a variable.

I think the issue is that inflate() is writing to a char* which is NULL terminated. I just don't know how to get it to be a string. I do fully anticipate this being a major oversight and a simple fix.  Thanks for any help!

Here's the decompression code:

```
bool DecompressString(const std::string& message, std::string& dMsg)
{
    int bufferSize = 512;
    int messageSize = message.size() + 1;
    //decompress string
    z_stream zs;
    memset(&zs, 0, sizeof(zs));

    zs.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    zs.zfree = Z_NULL;
    zs.opaque = Z_NULL;
    zs.next_in = (Bytef*)message.data();
    zs.avail_in = messageSize;

    int ret = Z_OK;
    unsigned char* outbuffer = new unsigned char[bufferSize];

    if (inflateInit2(&zs, 16+MAX_WBITS) == Z_OK)
    {
        do {
            zs.next_out = outbuffer;
            zs.avail_out = bufferSize;

            ret = inflate(&zs, Z_NO_FLUSH);

            if (ret < 0) return false;
            std::stringstream tmpString;
            tmpString << outbuffer;
            if (dMsg.size() < zs.total_out) {
                dMsg.append(tmpString.str().substr(0, zs.total_out - dMsg.size()));
            }
        } while (ret == Z_OK);
    }

    inflateEnd(&zs);
    delete[] outbuffer;
    //"\n<EOF>" is appended by sender to signify the end of file. This removes it
    if (dMsg.find("\n<EOF>") != -1)
        dMsg = dMsg.substr(0, dMsg.find("\n<EOF>"));

    return true;
}
```

Working code from solution:

```
bool DecompressString(const std::string& message, std::string& dMsg)
{
    int bufferSize = 512;
    int messageSize = message.size() + 1;
    //decompress string
    z_stream zs;
    memset(&zs, 0, sizeof(zs));

    zs.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    zs.zfree = Z_NULL;
    zs.opaque = Z_NULL;
    zs.next_in = (Bytef*)message.data();
    zs.avail_in = messageSize;

    int ret = Z_OK;
    unsigned char* outbuffer = new unsigned char[bufferSize];

    if (inflateInit2(&zs, 16+MAX_WBITS) == Z_OK)
    {
        // get the decompressed bytes blockwise using repeated calls to inflate
        do {
            zs.next_out = outbuffer;
            zs.avail_out = bufferSize;

            ret = inflate(&zs, Z_NO_FLUSH);

            if (ret < 0) return false;
            //Here's the difference
            if (dMsg.size() < zs.total_out)
                dMsg.append(reinterpret_cast<char*>(outbuffer), bufferSize);
            //End
        } while (ret == Z_OK);
    }

    inflateEnd(&zs);
    delete[] outbuffer;

    if (dMsg.find("\n<EOF>") != -1)
        dMsg = dMsg.substr(0, dMsg.find("\n<EOF>"));

    return true;
}
```

Comment: If you're working with binary data, you shouldn't use `string` or the formatted stream operators.

Comment: Ok, what should I use then?

Comment: Probably `vector<char>` and `vector::insert`.

Comment: I can't set zs.next_out to a vector. It expects an unsigned char* which I think is my problem due to them being null terminated.

Comment: You replace the string with a vector, not the buffer. And the buffer isn't zero-terminated in any way. It's very likely that binary data will contain zero bytes and mess up your string, but they're not terminators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string` is not a problem in itself, it can handle binary data.
It is this line that assumes a zero-terminated c-string:

```
tmpString << outbuffer;
```

Replace it with

```
tmpString.append(outbuffer, bufferSize);
```

Comment: I thought it'd be something simple like that. Thanks works like a charm.